# When does a servlet add Connection : close to its header?

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee, http-headers

I wrote a servlet that sends out XML data on PROPFIND requests. I must have done something special, since every response got in its header:
Connection : closed
which I don't write in there and which I actually don't want (some of the clients don't like that very much). What did I do? Or what do I need to do to avoid this?

:-( stw

Comment: What application server are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no hard and fast rule. It is at the discretion of the servlet container if and when a persistent connection request is terminated.